# Any CiviCRM integrations with Zapier or IFTTT?

Tags: developer, integration

There was a [forum thread](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35223.0) some months back regarding integrations with external tools like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) and [If This Then That (IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/), which automate tasks based on triggers between separate apps.

Has anyone worked on something in this regard? I don't have an immediate project in mind for this but I just got an email from IFTTT which reminded me of this thread and I was curious if anyone had taken it further as it seems like it could unlock a lot of potential.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be a good solution in the long run... you can automate so many things. Any updates on this? Is there a beta option, I can do some amazing things with Zapier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No progress been made on the Zapier integration. The customer in question thought it was nice for testing purposes and as a proof of contact but did not deem Zapiera good solution in the long run. So no funding.

Answer (score 1):

We did some work on Zapier integration but it was only half completed. I believe it  would provide a useful start for another developer to progress. Our partially built extension triggers the zap. Zapier integration only has 2 triggers as of now (create contact and update participant).

Comment: Is this your WIP?
https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.zapier

Comment: erm. nope. or yes but there is a second one that i see is set to Private currently. Checking for any reason it can't be set to Public.